# C# - Selenium - How to wait until page is fully loaded

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageload, webdriverwait

Due to slow synchronization on my testing website, I need to wait the page until is fully loaded. I have tried several elements waits like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='First Name']"))).SendKeys("FirstName");
```

Also I have attempt with JavaScript methods like:

```
public static void WaitForLoadOriginal(IWebDriver driver)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    int timeoutSec = 15;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeoutSec));
    wait.Until(wd => js.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").ToString() == "complete");
}
```

This is the code that i try to select

```
<select name="question" id="question1" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-required="true"
```

and this is the exception that i got:

An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll but was not handled in user code $exception {"Cannot locate option with index: 1"} OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

If I put `Thread.Sleep(20000)` in, it works fine. But I don't want to use static waits. Either I am not using the above methods properly, or they are not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your _HTML_ `<select name="question" id="question1" type="text" class="form-control...` and _code attempt_ `By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='First Name']")` is not matching.

Comment: IWebElement SecurityQuestion1 = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("question1")));
SelectElement DropDownSecurityQuestion1 = new SelectElement(SecurityQuestion1);
DropDownSecurityQuestion1.SelectByIndex(1);

Answer (score 2):

To perform waiting for page to load, this piece of code works with me fine.

```
protected void WaitForPageLoad()
    {
        wait.Until(driver=>((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As per your code block as you are trying to invoke **SendKeys()** along *WebDriverWait* instead of *ExpectedConditions* clause as *ElementExists* you sould use the clause [*ElementToBeClickable*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) as follows :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='First Name']"))).SendKeys("FirstName");
```

Comment: I tried with it. could not solve the issue. Still fails.

Comment: `could not solve` and `Still fails` doesn't throws any light on what wrong is happening. Update the question with relevant _HTML_, _code trial_ and _error stack trace_. As `Thread.Sleep(20000)` worked for you try increasing the timespan to **20 seconds**